# Pytest Triggers AssertionError: {}

Tags: python, error-handling, pytest, assertion

I'm following ex47 in Learn Python the Hardway by Zed Shaw, however, in the book he is using outdated software (Nose). I've converted his code/my code to pytest but I'm having some issues.

```
    def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom",
        """This room has gold in it you can grab.
        There's a door to the north.""")
#    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
#    assert_equal(gold.paths, {})
    assert gold.name, "GoldRoom"
    assert gold.paths, {}
```

I converted the Nose testing function asser_equal(a, b) to the Pytest equivalent: assert a, b. When I run it however, I get an error for just this one test. The other two tests pass in the same format. Furthermore, the error is pointed just at the line "assert gold.paths, {}".

```
>       assert gold.paths, {}
E       AssertionError: {}
E       assert {}
E        +  where {} = <ex47.game.Room object at 0x7fd136193be0>.paths
```

Pytest tells me that it passes if I change "assert gold.paths, {}" to "assert gold.paths == {}".
Is this a false positive? To me it reads the same, I am asserting that gold.paths equals a dictionary.

Can someone explain why the "==" symbol has to be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using assert with the comma is telling the assert statement to make *multiple* assertions. For example `assert 1==1, 2==2`.

In the case of `assert gold.name, "GoldRoom"` you're asking python to assert that `gold.name` and `"GoldRoom"` are non-empty-which they are. It's *not* actually testing equality between them.

For example try

```
num1 = 10
num2 =11
assert num1, num2
assert num1 == num2
```

The first assert will pass because the numbers are greater than 0 (and hence as a bool true). The second will fail because the numbers are not equal.

> I am asserting that gold.paths equals a dictionary

You're asserting the *value*, not the *type*. To assert that `gold.paths` is a dict, the correct assertion is `assert type(gold.paths) == dict`

More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement)